# What does this group theory notation mean: $\cap_{(x \in G)}xHx^{-1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

I came across on this website [1](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/4-ways-to-show-a-group-is-not-simple) the notation $\cap_{(x \in G)}xHx^{-1}$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. What does this mean?

Comment: The answer is in a footnote at the bottom of the page you linked to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a set,
$$xHx^{-1}=\{xhx^{-1}\mid h\in H \}.$$
It is a nice exercise to show that
$$\bigcap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1}$$
is a normal subgroup of $G$ (by construction essentially) and that it is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. This thing is called [the core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(group_theory)) of $H$.

Comment: It may worth adding that it is the kernel of the action of $G$ by left multiplication on the set of the left cosets of $H$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a big intersection of all sets $xHx^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$.

Each of those sets is actually of the form: $xHx^{-1}=\{xhx^{-1}: h\in H\}$ and is another subgroup of $G$ (a "conjugate" of $H$).

You may know that intersection of arbitrarily many subgroups of $G$ is again a subgroup of $G$, so the whole thing $\bigcap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1}$ is another subgroup of $G$. It can be shown that it is a normal subgroup of $G$ (even if $H$ isn't necessarily).

Answer (score 0):

We call this the core(H) in G. That is the largest normal subgroup of “G” contained in the subgroup H.